# copy excel cell from a range if criteria matches

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two tables with agent information from different programs. If an agent is in both programs I need to add in the data from the second table into the first. The criteria I am looking at is agent email. I have the vlookup formula VLOOKUP(C2,Sheet3!A1:O6530,6,FALSE). The data in the second table I am trying to pull the data from is column 6 , but I get an error with that formula for agents I know are in both programs. Any help is appreciated.

table to paste data to

[image]

table to copy data from

[image]

Comment: We will need more information, please see [mcve].  Please [edit] the post to include a mock up of the data in both tables that demonstrates the error.

Comment: @ScottCraner added screenshots

Comment: you are looking in column A of the lookup table not c for the match change the VLOOKUP:  `=VLOOKUP(C2,Sheet3!C1:O6530,3,FALSE)`  The left most column in the reference range is the column in which the vlookup will look for the match.

Comment: yep that fixed it, thanks! @ScottCraner